# Looking for database driven websites which are based on cloud computing

Tags: cloud-hosting

I want to have a website with database and customize the website to update data in the database. Can you suggest any cloud service which offer websites like these?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [google app engine](http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/appengine/), [Amazon Cloud services](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), or [Microsoft Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/)?